# python iterate loop and change values in dictionary

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

[image]

I'm trying to iterate over the loop to change the value of the dictionary. lines have a different baseball teams in each line . When I print the years, it prints out the keys correctly, but the value is all changed to the last element of the lines.
For example,
1903: 'NY Yankees', 1905: 'NY Yankees' ... 2021: 'NY Yankees'.
How do I make it to assign the correct values into the dictionary?

```
    lines = a.readlines()
    print(lines)
    for i in range(1903,2022):
        if i == 1904:
            continue
        elif i == 1994:
            continue
        else:
            years.update({i:i})
            for j in lines:
                years.update({i:j})
```

I expect to get when I print years,
1903:'First line in the lines', 1905: 'Second line in the lines' ...
What really resulted:
1903: 'Last element in lines' 1905: 'Last element in lines' ...

Comment: Dictionary keys are unique: for j in lines: years.update({i:j})  will update years[i] several times, keeping only the latest value, which will be the last line!

Comment: `years.update({i:i})` What is the point of this line?

Comment: @John Gordon: probably creating the dictionary keys in a first pass. But indeed it could be done in a simpler way.

Comment: @JohnGordon: It's a very silly way to do `years[i] = i` I've seen new Python programmers do far too often. They like the named methods, and forget the syntax.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I was hoping poster would explain _why_ they want to do `years[i] = i`.  Seems like a silly operation altogether.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dictionary keys are unique: for j in lines: years.update({i:j}) will update years[i] several times, keeping only the latest value, which will be the last line!

To fix that, iterate simultaneously on years' keys and on the lines like this:
Note the you must unindent this to pull it out of your else: bloc .

Here's the complete code, with the creation of the keys simplified:

```
lines = a.readlines()
print(lines)
years = {}
years_list = [i for i in range(1903,2022) if i != 1904 and i != 1994]
years = dict(zip(years_list,lines))
```

Comment: Even more simply, replace the definition of `years` and the loop with just `years = dict(zip(years_list, lines))`; the whole loop is pointless, and making a bazillion temp `dict`s makes it worse.

Comment: You're right, thanks for your insight. I updated my solution.